# Run a windows form application on Raspberry Pi made using C#

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, exe, raspbian

I neeed to run a windows form application on Raspberry Pi made using C#.

I have tried the option of installing a windows os and running the exe application . It does work but the issue is that it is slow and takes a lot of time for the application to work.

Is there any possibility to run the exe directly on raspbian ?

Comment: Not unless you can get it working under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). It does its best - some things work, some things don't, and often you have to do a lot of tweaking of fiddly settings. Good luck.

Comment: Short answer: no. You always need a dotnet runtime. I am not sure if there is anything available for raspbian/arm ...

Comment: There is in fact a How-To here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment But I am in doubt if that supports WinForms ... Can you add the specific Pi Model, Raspbian Version and dotnet platform you are (planning to be) using?

Comment: @Fildor that would only be for .NET Core / .NET 5 applications. No earlier .NET Framework apps would be runnable via that method. It's unclear which version this app was built using. And WinForms is purely Windows-only, in every version of .NET. As well as Wine there's a very small chance the app might run unmodified via [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/), but most things would need some porting work.

Comment: @ADyson Correct. In general, I would consider WinForms a poor choice of UI Framework for Applications that are targeted to multiple Platforms and Linux / ARM in particular.

Comment: @Fildor absolutely it's completely unsuitable for those scenarios. OP didn't really explain why they are trying to run this on Linux rather than re-writing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't natively run winform applications under Linux, but maybe you could try using Wine or one of the other compatibility tools for Linux.

If you are the author of the application you could port your app to [GTK#](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/) which is a desktop GUI Toolkit for Linux with C#

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using right now:
You can execute Windows Forms Applications written in the .NET Framework (newest 4.8, no longer continued) with [mono](https://www.mono-project.com/).
On the raspberry pi, if I recall correctly, you can "**sudo apt install mono-complete**" and then run it via the terminal: "**mono YourApp.exe**"
As I said, it sadly only works with .NET Framework Applications (or maybe on rare occasions with .NET 6.0 too, hasn't worked for mine though), you may be able to change that in Visual Studio though (or new project and then copy/paste the code).
The only downside is that you are then using an older version of C#, meaning some things may be different from what you are used to.